# I would like some help on the WordPress posts_per_page

Tags: wordpress

I have the index.php page the following code in the administration panel has 2 offering select the Admin option to select which category will be displayed on the block a home page and which category will be displayed on the block two home page

```
$block_one = array('category_name' => $block_cat_one->name,
    'posts_per_page' => 3, 'orderby' => 'rand');

$block_two = array('category_name' => $block_cat_two->name,
    'posts_per_page' => 3, 'orderby' => 'rand');
```

My question is the following code works normal for goal I want. More I want to know is be this query is correct on the same page have two `posts_per_page => 3`, it would not harm the system performance, it is not because it works it's right this is my doubt. I thank everyone for the feedback!

Sorry my English is not very good.

Comment: `posts_per_page = 3` will not cause any system performance issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Issues. You can use it as much as you want.